# How to combine and plot interpolating functions defined over two different ranges

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have defined interpolating functions over two different ranges.

```
A = Interpolation[{{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 20}.{4, 2}}]
B = Interpolation[{{2, 15}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {5, 2}}]
```

Now, I want to combine these in a single plot as follows:

```
Plot[{A[x], B[x]}, {x, 1, 5}]
```

It results in an error—`"InterpolatingFunction: Input value \!\(\*RowBox[{\" {\", \" 1.0000817142857144 \", \"} \"}]\) \ lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.  Extrapolation will be used"`.
The possible reason for this error could be that `x=1` lies outside the interpolation region of `B`.

Is there a way to plot these interpolated functions together?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not avoid extrapolation by using a common plot range? e.g. Plot[{A[x], B[x]}, {x, 2, 4}]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define how to handle extrapolation:

```
a = Interpolation[{{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 20}, {4, 2}}, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
     "WarningMessage" -> False}];
b = Interpolation[{{2, 15}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {5, 2}}, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
     "WarningMessage" -> False}];

Plot[{a[x], b[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Would this work?

```
a = Interpolation[{{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 20} . {4, 2}}]
b = Interpolation[{{2, 15}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {5, 2}}]

ListLinePlot[
  {a, b},
  PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 2
]
```

[image: plot of both]

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

a = Interpolation[{{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 20}, {4, 2}}];
b = Interpolation[{{2, 15}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {5, 2}}];
```

Define functions that are conditioned to only evaluate in the appropriate interval

```
ac[x_ /; 1 <= x <= 4] := a[x]
bc[x_ /; 2 <= x <= 5] := b[x]

Plot[{ac[x], bc[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]